# Parsing text in a pattern

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I'm trying to parse this text: http://pastebin.com/4Y7ggJjr in c#, but I don't really know how I should do it.

It looks like there's 4 blank lines, then there is information and so on.

Anyone know how I should approach this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Regular Expressions seem a good fit for this type of problem.

Comment: @wdosanjos I tried something with a streamreader. Didn't really work out. But I will try to use some method of parsing this using ragex. I'll be back

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any effort/research

Comment: @Tokfrans Can you explain why it didn''t work out? I tried something like this before using the ReadLine method. I might be able to help.  Basically I'd do a while loop, skip the blank lines until it's done searching the entire text.

Comment: @chris_techno25 That was exactly what I was doing. But I was not able to parse data on the same line. For instance on line 6. There's two things I want, the number (1) and the name (LRAD)

Comment: @Tokfrans The thing is...ReadLine reads the entire line as one, and this is normal. When the pointer reaches this kind, you'll have to use substring to separate the number and the text that follows. A  good solution would be to parse the text until it sees the first '.'. The rest would be the text after the number. At least that's what I did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines` to read the lines in the file and  `Enumerable.Where` to to take only lines which contain text. Then you can use `GroupBy` to create groups of three lines since one song seems to contain always three lines (duration,title,interpreter):

```
List<Song> songs = File.ReadLines(path)
    .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
    .Select((line, index) => new { line, index })  
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 3)  // integer division trick
    .Select(grp => new Song
    {
        Duration = TimeSpan.Parse(grp.First().line.Trim()),
        Title = grp.ElementAt(1).line.Trim(),
        Interpreter = grp.ElementAt(2).line.Trim()
    }).ToList();
```

Here's a custom class to store all informations:

```
public class Song
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Interpreter { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**: [Here's](http://ideone.com/drMfo9) a demo with your sample data which outputs:

```
1. LRAD from Knife Party [05:15:00]
2. Hymn from His Majesty Andre [05:49:00]
3. Saturn from Kill The Noise, Brillz, Minxx [05:33:00]
4. Wayfarer - Original Mix from Audien [06:00:00]
5. Heads Will Roll - A-Trak Radio Edit from Yeah Yeah Yeahs, A-Trak [03:24:00]
6. Summertime Sadness [Lana Del Rey vs. Cedric Gervais] - Cedric Gervais Remix from Lana Del Rey, Cedric Gervais [06:53:00]
7. EDM Death Machine from Knife Party [04:23:00]
8. Leaving You - Radio Edit from Audien, Michael S. [03:34:00]
9. Astrocat from Pixl [05:22:00]
10. Chronicles Of A Fallen Love - Tom Swoon Remix from The Bloody Beetroots, Greta Svabo Bech [05:41:00]
11. Reason - Radio Edit from Nervo, Hook n Sling [03:34:00]
12. Power Glove from Knife Party [04:22:00]
13. Polar - Original Mix from Fire Flowerz [04:19:00]
14. Enjoy - Oliver Remix from Gigamesh [05:39:00]
15. In My Mind (Axwell Remix) from Ivan Gough & Feenixpawl feat. Georgi Kay [06:41:00]
16. Stellar - Radio Edit from Daddy's Groove [03:19:00]
17. Reason - TV Noise Remix from Liv Nervo, Nervo, Hook n Sling, Miriam Nervo [04:04:00]
18. Galactic Voyage from Pixl [06:36:00]
19. Iron Hill from Fire Flowerz [04:08:00]
20. Harmony from Vicetone [06:17:00]
21. Stars - Original Mix from Vicetone, Jonny Rose [05:15:00]
22. Self Destruct from Pegboard Nerds, Various Artists [03:33:00]
23. Pressure Cooker from Pegboard Nerds, Various Artists [03:14:00]
24. Razor Sharp from Pegboard Nerds & Tristam [04:42:00]
25. Dreams (feat. Laura Brehm) from Rogue, Laura Brehm [04:17:00]
26. Internet Friends - VIP from Knife Party [05:01:00]
27. How We Do - Original Mix from Hardwell, Showtek [05:27:00]
28. Slow Down - Radio Edit from Showtek [03:27:00]
29. Get Loose from Showtek, Noisecontrollers [05:35:00]
30. Unison - Knife Party Remix from Porter Robinson [04:59:00]
31. Stars - Original Mix from Vicetone, Jonny Rose [05:15:00]
32. Flight from Tristam, Braken [03:40:00]
33. Imagine Reality from Uppermost [04:57:00]
34. 5-HT - Kat Krazy Remix from The Good Natured [03:36:00]
35. D.A.N.C.E. from Justice [04:03:00]
36. Alive from Krewella [04:51:00]
37. Lights from Steve Angello, Third Party [05:09:00]
38. We Come Running - Vicetone Remix from Youngblood Hawke [05:48:00]
39. Live for the Night from Krewella [03:28:00]
40. We Come Running - TiÃ«sto Remix from Youngblood Hawke [04:30:00]
41. Damaged - Radio Edit from Adrian Lux [02:46:00]
42. Teenage Crime - Radio Edit from Adrian Lux [02:51:00]
43. You Make Me from Avicii [03:53:00]
44. Wild Child - Radio Edit from Adrian Lux, Marcus SchoÌˆssow, JJ [02:42:00]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] lines = stringWithAllTextFromTheFileInIt.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries });
```

This will give you all the unblank lines in a string array. If you add more detail to what you want, I can write a Regex for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
    var text = File.ReadAllText("someTextFile.txt");
    var values = text.Trim('\n').Trim('\t').Trim('\r').Split(' ');
```

You can then iterate through your values as they are gathered in one array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int cnt = 0;
var result = File.ReadLines(filename)
                .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                .GroupBy(line => cnt++ / 3)
                .Select(g => String.Join(Environment.NewLine, g.Select(x => x.Trim())))
                .ToList();
```

which would return 47 items.

Comment: @TimSchmelter didn't know those methods are copyrighted. SO is full of similar answers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Beeing 17 minutes late doesn't make it invalid. I didn't want to throw it away and posted it. BTW: there are many answers that *selects the index and then does grouping using that index* Why did you post that answer instead of referring one of them, if you think this answer is the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter So since you think your answer is better I should delete mine because I am 17 minutes late and used `ReadLines` and `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` ?